# rails unicorn install error with kgio 2.8.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

i am trying to add unicorn to one of my rails apps on heroku - i've added the unicorn config file and the unicorm gem to the gemfile but when i try to bundle install on my windows dev machine i get:

```
An error occurred while installing kgio (2.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

i tried 'gem install kgio -v "2.8.0' and get similar errors.
i am running ruby  1.9.3p125. 
One of the posts said something about it only running in a Unix [nonwindows] environment. 
i guess i really only need it running on heroku on my production system.

any suggestions?

Comment: i tried moving the unicorn gem to the production group in the gemfile to try to avoid the windows issue on my windows dev machine and it still chokes trying to load kgio as above.

Comment: i think i found a solution:in gemfile specify platform specific execution of unicorn gem; e.g.    platforms :ruby do # linux
  gem 'unicorn'
end