# ROR + An error occurred while installing kgio (2.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Same Question I think : [Rails-Unicorn-Install-Error-KGIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388631/rails-unicorn-install-error-with-kgio-2-8-0)

While running bundle install, system is giving error for installing gems.

```
Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/kgio-2.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.8.
0/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing kgio (2.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here I am unable to install `kgio` gem. I tried a lot but no success. Is there any way to come out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Removed the Unicorn gem from gem list.

```
gem 'unicorn'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 7:

[Error Installing "kgio-2.9.2" Gem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234917/error-installing-kgio-2-9-2-gem-on-windows)

`platforms :ruby do 
  gem 'unicorn'
end`